# Sense hat IMU not working on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to use the Sense Hat with Ubuntu 22.10, and I've installed the Python SenseHat library.  The matrix display is working, but not the IMU.

What I've diagnosed so far:

```
$ groups
joachim dialout sudo video input gpio spi i2c

$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- 5f 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6a -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

$ RTIMULibDrive11 
Settings file not found. Using defaults and creating settings file
I2C slave select 28 failed - 
No IMU detected
Using fusion algorithm RTQF
Detected MS5611 at standard address
Detected HTU21D at standard address
No IMU found
```

The 'UU' output from i2cdetect seems to mean "Probing was skipped, because this address is currently in use by a driver".

This is the output from `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             24576  1
algif_skcipher         20480  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   32768  2
hci_uart              151552  1
btqca                  24576  1 hci_uart
btrtl                  24576  1 hci_uart
btbcm                  28672  1 hci_uart
btintel                45056  1 hci_uart
btsdio                 20480  0
bluetooth             811008  30 btrtl,btqca,btsdio,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
binfmt_misc            24576  1
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
imx219                 24576  1
brcmfmac              421888  0
rpisense_fb            20480  1
rpisense_js            20480  0
bcm2835_unicam         61440  0
fb_sys_fops            20480  1 rpisense_fb
st_pressure_spi        16384  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 rpisense_fb
brcmutil               28672  1 brcmfmac
sysfillrect            20480  1 rpisense_fb
st_magn_spi            16384  0
v4l2_dv_timings        36864  1 bcm2835_unicam
sysimgblt              16384  1 rpisense_fb
bcm2835_codec          53248  0
rpivid_hevc            65536  0
st_sensors_spi         16384  2 st_pressure_spi,st_magn_spi
bcm2835_isp            36864  0
bcm2835_v4l2           45056  0
v4l2_fwnode            32768  2 imx219,bcm2835_unicam
v4l2_mem2mem           49152  2 bcm2835_codec,rpivid_hevc
st_pressure_i2c        16384  0
bcm2835_mmal_vchiq     40960  3 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,bcm2835_isp
raspberrypi_hwmon      16384  0
cfg80211              995328  1 brcmfmac
v4l2_async             28672  3 v4l2_fwnode,imx219,bcm2835_unicam
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_dma_contig    24576  4 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_unicam,rpivid_hevc,bcm2835_isp
snd_bcm2835            32768  0
st_magn_i2c            16384  0
videobuf2_memops       20480  2 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_dma_contig
st_magn                20480  2 st_magn_i2c,st_magn_spi
st_pressure            20480  2 st_pressure_i2c,st_pressure_spi
st_sensors_i2c         16384  2 st_pressure_i2c,st_magn_i2c
st_sensors             28672  6 st_pressure,st_pressure_i2c,st_magn_i2c,st_pressure_spi,st_magn,st_magn_spi
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  6 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_unicam,bcm2835_v4l2,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,bcm2835_isp
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  2 st_pressure,st_magn
snd_pcm               167936  1 snd_bcm2835
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
videobuf2_common       81920  10 bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_v4l2,bcm2835_unicam,bcm2835_v4l2,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_memops,bcm2835_isp
snd_timer              49152  1 snd_pcm
videodev              286720  10 v4l2_async,bcm2835_codec,imx219,videobuf2_v4l2,bcm2835_unicam,bcm2835_v4l2,videobuf2_common,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,bcm2835_isp
industrialio          110592  9 st_pressure,industrialio_triggered_buffer,st_sensors,st_pressure_i2c,kfifo_buf,st_magn_i2c,st_pressure_spi,st_magn,st_magn_spi
snd                   126976  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
vc_sm_cma              40960  2 bcm2835_mmal_vchiq,bcm2835_isp
mc                     73728  10 v4l2_async,videodev,bcm2835_codec,imx219,videobuf2_v4l2,bcm2835_unicam,videobuf2_common,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,bcm2835_isp
bcm2835_gpiomem        16384  0
nvmem_rmem             16384  0
uio_pdrv_genirq        20480  0
uio                    28672  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
dm_multipath           40960  0
pstore_blk             16384  0
pstore_zone            28672  1 pstore_blk
drm                   638976  0
ramoops                32768  0
reed_solomon           28672  1 ramoops
ip_tables              36864  0
x_tables               57344  1 ip_tables
autofs4                49152  2
btrfs                1646592  0
blake2b_generic        24576  0
raid10                 69632  0
raid456               204800  0
async_raid6_recov      24576  1 raid456
async_memcpy           20480  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_pq               20480  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_xor              20480  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               20480  5 async_pq,async_memcpy,async_xor,raid456,async_raid6_recov
xor                    20480  2 async_xor,btrfs
xor_neon               20480  1 xor
raid6_pq              114688  4 async_pq,btrfs,raid456,async_raid6_recov
libcrc32c              16384  2 btrfs,raid456
raid1                  57344  0
raid0                  24576  0
multipath              24576  0
linear                 20480  0
rpisense_core          16384  2 rpisense_js,rpisense_fb
spidev                 24576  0
i2c_mux_pinctrl        16384  0
i2c_mux                16384  1 i2c_mux_pinctrl
dwc2                  311296  0
roles                  20480  1 dwc2
udc_core               77824  1 dwc2
spi_bcm2835            28672  0
i2c_bcm2835            20480  0
crct10dif_ce           20480  1
xhci_pci               24576  0
xhci_pci_renesas       24576  1 xhci_pci
phy_generic            20480  1
aes_arm64              16384  3
```

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments, I've verified that the SenseHat indeed works using Raspi OS:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1c -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5c -- -- 5f 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6a -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ RTIMULibDrive11 
Settings file not found. Using defaults and creating settings file
Detected LSM9DS1 at standard/standard address
Using fusion algorithm RTQF
Detected LPS25H at standard address
Detected HTS221 at standard address
min/max compass calibration not in use
Ellipsoid compass calibration not in use
Accel calibration not in use
LSM9DS1 init complete
Sample rate 0: : roll:7.131833, pitch:-60.197531, yaw:-174.524598
Pressure: 1034.6, height above sea level: -176.1, temperature: 23.9, humidity: 40.2
```

Comment: Does it work with Raspi OS?  That will help answer your question.